# What term describes the quality of code which makes it easily testable?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, singleton, terminology

There is this JS library I'm using which has a singleton design. When I attempt to use the library in many different tests, the library's global state from the previous test is contaminating the next test. I would say "the problem here is that the library is using the Singleton pattern, thus is not easily testable".

What term describes the "testable" quality that this library *is lacking?*

I want to say, that this library should be refactored so that it:

- becomes *"easily testable?"*
- is *"not a singleton?"*
- can *"handle plurality?"*
- can *"handle 'arity'?"*

What is the correct way for me to describe the quality that I would like this library to incorporate such that it is more easily testable?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not actually a programming problem.

Comment: referentially transparent ?

Comment: Might be a better fit for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this paper](http://www.satisfice.com/tools/testability.pdf) on testability, you are concerned with the **controlability** of the object/class. You are having difficulty directing the object into a specific state for the test. You are unable to invoke a desired state for the purpose of testing.

**Controlability** is part of a product's intrinsic testabilty, i.e. the aspect of testabilty related to the product itself, not its environment or behaviors of the people around it.